# Как работать с командной строкой ubuntu при запущенном py скрипте?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

Как мне работать со строкой, когда я запустил py-файл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ctrl+C? . . . .

Comment: Утилита screen Вам в помощь. Если я понял о чём речь

Comment: Почему бы не запустить ещё один терминал?

Answer (score 1):

Есть несклько вариантов:
можно запускать скрипт, добавив в конце `&` - это приведет к тому, что скрипт будет запущеy в бэкграунде (но стоит учитывать, что stdout все равно будет смотреть в консоль).

Так же во время работы скрипта можно нажать `ctrl+z`, что приведет к отправке скрипту `SIGSTOP`, его останову (он не будет продолжать работу в бэкграунде), и отдаст обратно консоль. Дальше можно разрешить скрипту выполняться в бэкграунде с помощью `bg %{job_id}` (job_id можно узнать запустив `jobs`), либо вернуться к выполнению в переднем плане, с помощью `fg %{job_id}` или просто `%`.

Answer (score -1):

Судя по всему, скрипт ожидает ввод какой-то информации для обработки. В консоли можно ввести что-либо и нажать enter, скрипт получит введённую информацию и попробует её обработать.
Для выхода, по идее, можно попробовать снять задание через Ctrl+C.

Если вопрос в том, что нужно ввести, чтобы получить какой-то полезный результат, то хорошо бы посмотреть на сам скрипт.

Comment: Почему не  Ctrl + D?